# What is the meaning of this "Let those who wait, will wait"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Please explain the meaning of the idiom "Let those who wait, will wait!"

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it isn't "Let those who will wait, wait"?

Comment: I added a picture from my phone.

Comment: So it was a machine translation from another language? Machine translations often don't produce good English.

Comment: This text misleading. That is why I wrote here. 
Probably it would be better to say "Let those who wait will have wait"?

Comment: What meaning are you trying to convey?

Comment: The person who waits for something. Finally, this person will have waited for it in the future.

Comment: I'd write that as "Those who wait will have waited".

Comment: It is wrong. It should be "Let those [who will wait] wait." The usual structure is : Let + object + base form of verb.

Comment: It is wrong. It should be "Let those [who will wait] wait." The usual structure is : Let + object + base form of verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an idiom. It's almost certainly a simple mistake. (Either a typo or translation error.)

There are two expressions that would normally be used instead:

> Let those who wait, wait.
>   Those who wait will wait.

But rather than use one of those (or a similar variation), somebody inappropriately combined the two.

---

Nonetheless, the meaning is essentially the same.

It means that there is an order to things. For instance, anybody who is in a line, waiting to get to the front, needs to wait their turn.

So, those who are in line (who are waiting), need to continue to wait until it's their turn.

A shorter expression, directed at the person who is waiting, is just *be patient*.

Comment: It could also be a mistake for "Let those who will, wait.", meaning if you are willing to wait, do it, or if you aren't , go getem!